# if inside for loop not working for each iteration jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check condition given inside if statement but it is not working. For loop is not iterating through all array elements. It is just giving first element of array. When i remove if statement this works fine. What is the issue? Below is my code:

```
$("label").click(function(){
  var optionVal = ($(this).attr('id'));
  var arr = [];
  var arra = [];
  var i = 0;

  {% for image in product.images %} 
    arr[i++] = ('{{ image.src | product_img_url: 'grande' }}');
  {% endfor %}

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].match(optionVal)) {
      $(".product__slideshow-image").attr("src", arr[i]); // change the image source           
      alert(arr[i]);  
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: try addin alert(arr[i].match(optionVal); to your code, see what is passed to the if statement

Comment: [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) requires a regular expression as its argument, and you're passing a string, unless for some ungodly reason the ID of your element is a valid regular expression...

Comment: @paris93 alert(arr[i].match(optionval)) is working only on first element. It seems i is not incrementing.

Comment: put arr[i].match(optionval); before the if statement, and try putting alert(i) before the if statement too, see what it gives you, it's strange that i isn't incrementing because your for loop looks fine

Comment: @paris93 alert(i) is giving 0 as output. Value of i should increase but it is not increasing inside if statement. Works fine when alert(i) is used after losing if statement. i value increases outside if statement.